# Как организовать поиск LIKe по нескольки подстрокам для одного поля

Tags: sql, mysql

привет.
припустим нужно найти поиск по 2 и более подстрокам для одного поля.
Я хочу получить что-то вида :

```
`col` LIKE '%world1%' AND '%otherworld2%'`
```

(этот синтаксис вызовет ошибку)

Можно конечно поступить так:

```
`col` LIKE '%world1%otherworld2%' `
```

Но ведь второе словое может итди перед первым,тогда :

```
`col` LIKE '%otherworld2%world1%' `
```

Но если будет более 2 слов ?

Как лучше поступить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`col` LIKE '%world1%' AND `col` LIKE '%otherworld2%'`
```